# Debug with mono d

Tags: debugging, monodevelop, d

I'm trying to use mono d to develop some vibe.d applications and I'm having trouble with the debugger. Sometimes I can't see the content of some variables. Also, in order to have any symbols at all, I need to remove my complete "buildTypes" configuration in my dub.json.

Also, when starting a debug session, I get this:
"&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permited\n""

Finally, I cannot stop my application using the mono d "stop" command. I always need to use the kill -9 on my application or else it keeps running.

Any idea how to solve these issues?

In general I'm struggling to find a confortable working environment. Tried Visual Studio+VisualD, Eclipse+DDT, and Monodevelop+Mono-D, but all have their issues, almost always related to debugging. What is everyone else using?

Thanks a lot,
Mario

Comment: Well, you mentioned you're looking for a confortable working environment: what I use: Mono + windbg (http://dlang.org/windbg.html) to me it's just fine. I remember I failed to get gdb working.

Answer (score 2):

1. GBD based debugging is not that good in Mono-D. Eclipse can understand more of D constructs by my opinion, but the best option there is to use VisualD w/ Mago. Unfortunatelly current version of Mago makes VS 2013 very unstable.
2. Could you please put there your failing dub.json configuration?
3. I'm assuming you are using an Ubuntu with a recent version of GDB. You can ignore this warning, it's beacuse of some GDB 7.x vs GNOME terminal thing, I'm sure that will be fixed soon. As a workaround you can use Mono's integrated terminal for debugging.
4. I ain't have this "stop" issue. Which version of Monodevelop and Mono-D are you using? It is advised to use a recent beta instead of the stable release, I'm using Monodevelop 5.6 right now without any issues.

I think Mono-D + Linux is by far the best option that you could have for D development right now despite it's issues.